# Is it possible to download asset(s) from Unity asset store, outside Unity application?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I am trying to download any asset from the asset store inside Unity application, the asset download bar shows `Error` (first shows 0% and then shows `Error`).

I guess unity assets are kept somewhere on the cloud which my firewall is closing. Is there any work around to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Faced with the same problem. Solved in this way:
To download content open "Windows -> Asset store"
Then, instead of the Download button click on the asset name
Then it opened in the embedded browser description of asset click download button in this asset description window